# Isomorphism between $S^{2n-1}$ and U(n)/U(n-1)

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

I've read that $S^{2n-1} ≃ U(n)/U(n-1)$,and the motivation starts considering that $U(n)$ acts transitively on $S^{2n-1}$, and the isotropy subgroup of $e_{1}=(1,0,...,0)\in S^{2n-1}$ are those matrices of the form
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&A'\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so that $U(n-1) ≃ Iso(e_{1})$. This should also imply that $U(n)/Iso(e_{1}) ≃ e_{1}U(n)$, so my question is:- Can I say that $S^{2n-1} ≃ U(n)/U(n-1)$ is due to the fact that, given $M\in U(n)$, I've always
$$(e_{1}M)(e_{1}M)^{\dagger}=e_{1}MM^{\dagger}e_{1}^{\dagger}=1$$
or this is not the way to prove it?